# Send a GET-request after app starts listening

Tags: node.js, express

I know this is unorthodox, but I was wondering if there's a way to use a redirect inside of the app.listen, something like this:

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  //res.redirect("some url")
})
```

The fact is I need to launch a **GET request** after the app is on listen mode, after some research I've found it could be done with a redirect; clearly, I don't have a routing and a response object res to afford it.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Who has to make the get request? Your node process, something like server to server?

Comment: The node process itself should make that request after it starts correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply run an http request in your ready handler function.
For instance you could use the `request` package:

```
const request = require('request');
app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  request('http://your.url', function (error, response, body) {
    // do something with the response
  });
})
```

Of coure you'll need to `npm i request` in order for the above example to work and you can choose whatever http client you prefer and replace it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Wonder why was this so hard to find on the internet...